How to represent maxItems in OpenAPI schema when it is unknown?
I'm running my OpenAPI schema through an audit process and, in two scenarios, it is complaining that the schema defines arrays without specifying maxItems. The two scenarios are:
a) APIs that return paginated information, and the API itself allows the size of the page to be set and the index into the set of pages.
b) APIs that return arrays of errors.
In all cases, I am unable to specify a maximum number.
The clearest example is specifying the page number into the set of results. If we have (say) 10,000 customers and a page size of 10, the highest page number would be 1,000. But if the page size is 1, the maximum would be 10,000.
In theory, I could put a stupidly high number in the schema, like 1 million, but is there a better way to handle this or is that the only workaround?
It seems that the specification requires a maximum to be specified.

For a), is there a maximum allowed page size, e.g. 100 or 1000? Page sizes are typically limited.

@Helen there is a default page size of 10, but we don't have have an upper limit on the page size - not currently, anyway.

this is likely for an availability concern, openapi doesn't require it - would you really want to return megabytes or gigabytes of data on a single endpoint?

OpenAPI and JSON Schema do not require maxItems for arrays. This error probably comes from a linter that enforces the use of certain keywords for some reason.
Your options are:

Actually implement maxItems for those arrays and limit the maximum allowed page sizes accordingly.

Add an arbitrarily high maxItems to the schema and hope your API will never actually exceed it.

Disable the maxItems linter check for those schemas - if the linter provides such an option.


